# Too many relationships being returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner to neo4j.  I've walked through the tutorial.  I've built my data, and loaded it into a graphdb and I'm trying to validate that it imported correctly.

I'm not sure if the problem I'm having is something I'm doing in the import or in the cypher query.

I'm using [this import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) to import the following files (the below has been filtered to just contain the rows I'm currently investigating):

application_id node file:

```
application_id:ID(application_id),:LABEL
2036983247,application_id
2037028183,application_id
```

personal_phone node file:

```
personal_phone:ID(personal_phone),:LABEL    
5555551234,personal_phone
```

relationship file:

```
:START_ID(personal_phone),:END_ID(application_id),:TYPE
5555551234,2036983247,APPLIED
5555551234,2037028183,APPLIED
```

My cypher query:

```
match p= (a {personal_phone:'5555551234'}) -->(b) return p
```

In my results I see that the personal_phone node has 2 'APPLIED' relationships with each of the application_id nodes.  I'd expect to see only one.  Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT :** This is what I see.  The center node is the `personal_phone` node.

[image]

**EDIT 2 :**  So I figured out that using the `dump` statement from the neo4j shell I could get an export of the database.  I figured I'd run it for the nodes in question:

```
$ dump match p= (a personal_phone:'5555551234'})-->(b) return p;
```

Returns:

```
begin
create (_5:`application_id` {`application_id`:"2036983247"})
create (_410:`application_id` {`application_id`:"2037028183"})
create (_6928:`personal_phone` {`personal_phone`:"5555551234"})
create _6928-[:`APPLIED`]->_410
create _6928-[:`APPLIED`]->_5
create _6928-[:`APPLIED`]->_410
create _6928-[:`APPLIED`]->_5
;
commit
```

This shows that I definitely have duplicate relationships.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh - dumb mistake in my import was the issue.  It went unnoticed because there were soo many different files being imported but basically I had the relationships file importing twice in my script file:

```
--relationships "f:\temp\r_personal_phone_application_id_APPLIED.csv" 
--relationships "f:\temp\r_personal_phone_application_id_APPLIED.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

You add two `APPLIED` relationships from a single `personal_phone` node to two different `application_id` nodes.

When you `MATCH` all relationships from this `personal_phone` node, you would indeed expect to get two `APPLIED` relationships as result.

Comment: Thanks.  Why don't I see the `application_id` nodes separated into two separate `application_id` nodes with a single `APPLIED` relationship going to each?

Comment: What DO you see? Are you talking about the web interface?

Comment: Updated my question with a picture showing the result I am getting, and yes - I mean the web interface.

Comment: And upon re-reading your answer, I guess I'm getting four `APPLIED` relationships as a result (not two).